# How to transform the email string to make the assignment a success using eval() in php

Tags: php, eval

I want to use the eval function in php to perform the assignment operation, but the value is email address which contains '@'. How should I transform the email string to make the assignment a success?

Comment: Do not use eval, there must be other way you can do, provide some of the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

DON'T USE EVAL.

There is almost no problem or function for which eval() is the best answer, there is always another approach.

Consider using an associative array for your variables, then `$data[$fieldname] = $email;` will give you the ability to dynamically assign the email into a field.

Comment: But I have to construct the associative array using string,actually I do not know what the $fieldname exactly are...

Comment: You will need to provide more information in the question then. If you could include the code that currently has the eval in it, and explain where the email address variable comes from and where it has to go, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($submittion->data as $key => $value) {
        $ele_key_array = webform_component_parent_keys($form['#node'], $form['#node']->webform['components'][$key]);
        $ele_key = "['" . implode("']['",$ele_key_array) . "']";
        $ele_value = implode(',', $value['value']);
        dsm($ele_value);
        @eval("\$form['submitted']" . $ele_key . "['#default_value']=$ele_value;");
    }
```

the codes are used in drupal to get the form key and set its default value